# Default cursor on mouse over of a button is not a hand pointer

Tags: buttons, css, hover, cursor

Why is the default cursor an arrow when you hover over an HTML `<button>`? I always thought that arrows let you select stuff, but hands let you execute an action. Since buttons execute actions, shouldn't I override the default style to be a hand pointer?

[image: button cursor hand]

```
button {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your question and noticed that SO uses hand cursor for votes, "add comment" button and... it is easier to find out which element is interactive this way, so screw official guidelines I am switching to this style :-).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Buttons are a traditional desktop software UI control - a context where the hand pointer has never been used before the advent of internet.

When web pages started to use the same control, they just kept the button as it was in a desktop environment.

Comment: If I were to use the hand pointer, would that increase or decrease usability? Personally, I prefer the hand pointer for consistency.

Comment: Consistency is also about user expectancies. And average users probably don't expect to find a pointer which is different from the one they are used to.

Comment: But so many buttons on the internet are links with an image background, and even those that aren't pretty commonly do have cursor:pointer (check the Add Comment button for an example) What are users used to at this point?

Comment: @franz976: Average users probably won't notice the difference, actually.

Comment: I would also like an answer to which is more usable. Most UI tweaks are pretty subliminal - users don't notice explicitly. But they make a difference. For example, in the question above I might think the button images in the question were actual buttons, but be alerted to the face that they're not because of the cursor. I noticed buttons on StackExchange sites have `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545459.aspx) is an excerpt from Microsoft's guidelines for *Windows-based applications*: *"To avoid confusion, it is imperative not to use the hand pointer for other purposes. For example, command buttons already have a strong affordance, so they don't need a hand pointer. The hand pointer must mean "this target is a link" and nothing else."*

Comment: Personally I also add cursors to buttons or anything that can be directly interacted with for that matter. I don't think that users will be confused/disoriented if you use the hand cursor instead of the default, if anything it will be more helpful.

Comment: Sometimes links are styled as buttons to show that they represent an action, even if they're implemented as HTML links. Should link-buttons be explicitly `cursor: default` to match `<button>`s and `<input type=submit>`s?

Comment: This is complete and total BS. http://www.loper-os.org/?p=568 Buttons with cursor happened before the Internet.

Answer (score 39):

It's all about **Affordance**. Buttons have a high affordance which visually suggest how they can be used. The hand pointer is used when affordance is lower to provide an indication of how to interact with that item.

Here's an extract from Microsoft's [Windows desktop applications > Design > Guidelines > Interaction > Mouse and Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dn742466.aspx))

> 'Well-designed user interface (UI)
> objects are said to have affordance,
> which are visual and behavioral
> properties of an object that suggest
> how it is used.'

And:

> Text and graphics links use a hand or "link select" pointer (a hand with the index finger pointing Screen shot of hand with index finger pointing  ) because of their weak affordance. While links may have other visual clues to indicate that they are links (such as underlines and special placement), displaying the hand pointer on hover is the definitive indication of a link.
>
> **To avoid confusion, it is imperative not to use the hand pointer for other purposes.** For example, command buttons already have a strong affordance, so they don't need a hand pointer. The hand pointer must mean "this target is a link" and nothing else.

Comment: Buttons probably have high affordance, but what's wrong with even greater affordance by using the hand pointer?

Comment: I think the affordance comment makes some sense and have given a +1, but I also still say that an interaction should be designed consistently across a site, even if it's a slightly different convention.

Comment: @JoJo I think it would send mixed messages: the hand is only for links (as a "link select" pointer) and nothing else. Its purpose is to supplement the poor affordance of a link, so Microsoft say to not dilute that message by also using it for something else (e.g. buttons).

Comment: Interestingly, microsoft.com in opposition with themselves, using the following CSS:
`button:not(:disabled) { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 13):

Both [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor) and [CSS Basic UI 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#cursor) specs definitely say that pointer cursor is *specifically for links* ('...a pointer *that indicates* a link'). One of the authors of the CSS 2.1 Test Suite wrote [a following remark](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-css-testsuite/2010Jul/0024.html) in W3C mailing list:

> Even when hovering the cursor over an <img onclick="...some
>   function...">, a push button, a radio button, a checkbox, the cursor
>   under Windows does not change into a pointer but remains an arrow.
>
> The pointer cursor is to indicate *a link* and *not* any/all clickable
>   objects. It's because web authors abuse cursor declaration or misuse
>   cursor declaration that there is a tendency to generalize or assume
>   things (like a cursor revealing clickability) that the spec does not
>   say.

So whether using `cursor:pointer` in other context than for links improves usability or not, it still violates the CSS standards.

Comment: What about when a button performs the same functionality as a link (i.e. goes to a new page, perhaps with javascript) or when a link doesn't actually go to a new page and does something dynamic instead? I think many sites blur the lines between buttons and links, and the more important thing is to indicate to the user that a thing can be clicked.

Comment: @Luke, I agree that this approach exists. But this is what the specifications say. Personally I believe that in good UI clickability of things should be obvious without cursor hints.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn CSS 2.1 spec explicitly doesn't say it's _exclusively_ for links. It just states "[t]he cursor is a pointer that indicates a link" as a link's `<a href="#"></a>` _default behavior_. Just citing one person's opinion on the standard's discussion list doesn't make it a standard's statement.

Comment: @VolkerE. but the spec doesn't say anything about 'default or non-default behavior' either, does it? It uses the word 'indicates', which I understand as 'helps to distinguish links and non-links'. There can be possibly a catch in the definition of what 'a link' is, but I can't find any example of a standard that defines a link as 'anything that can be clicked'.

Comment: Well, you've stated in your answer that "[t]he pointer cursor is _to_ indicate a link" [accentuation by myself], which simply isn't in the spec. If you compare the examples below the other values, they are widely vague as well. It's just an example for what is meant by `cursor: pointer`, best exemplified by what kind of cursor is shown at a link. There is *no* exclusivity specified at all.

Comment: @VolkerE. I don't agree that other examples are _that_ vague. E.g. example for `help` explicitly says 'Help is available for _the object under the cursor_', not 'the cursor is the one usually used for the object with the help available' or something. It clearly says that the cursor _means_ that user should expect that if something has `help` cursor, there should be some help available for it. And if something has cursor that _indicates a link_, user may expect link behavior from it (ability to copy and paste address, open in new tab etc.). Otherwise, it may confuse the user.

Answer (score 11):

Interestingly, hovering the submit button on *this* comment form changes the cursor to the hand. I would say "arrow=do and hand=go" was probably a convention at one point, but it's been widely discarded through a) ignorance to it and b) better design. Make a button look clickable and the cursor change won't matter to the end user.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bit about psychology too.  Changing the cursor too an arrow on mouseover indicates that the user is hovering on something that is actionable, but not necessarily an action that will take them somewhere else.  That's different than a hand icon on mouseover, which on the web, indicates they can go somewhere.

Comment: So any button that executes javascript and doesn't go to a new link should be an arrow? The hand pointer is exclusive for hyperlinks?

Comment: On the web, certainly from what I've seen in well over a decade doing this, the hand cursor is for hyperlinks.  In general, the pointer is for actionable items that happen on page or reload the same page. I tend to think of it as arrow=do and hand=go.  Of course you can easily change the cursor on a hover state with CSS, so it allows you to think of crosshairs, question marks (usually for definitions or acronyms) and many other possibilities.

Comment: Here's a counterexample. Look at Facebook's account link. It activates the hand cursor, but it doesn't go to a new link. Rather it opens a menu on the same page.

Comment: I've been completely off Facebook for a while now, so can't look at it live, but I'd also say that Facebook breaks a lot of convention around meeting expectations.  Do all the choices on the menu then go to other pages on Facebook?  If so, you 'could' say that the flow is about going elsewhere, with an intermediary menu in the mix.

Comment: Most of Stackexchange's buttons have hand pointers too...

Comment: Yes, but in the markup they are (at least the one at the bottom of this form) <input type="button" /> whereas, a more traditional input type for the submit function on a form is <input type="submit" />.  The default cursor on each of these is/can be different and is totally editable via CSS.  I can tell any kind of markup to use any kind of cursor, but it doesn't mean the choice I've made is standard or even following any kind of convention.  A designer really needs to decide what kind of visual cue makes sense and apply it consistently.

Comment: I think that (out-of-context) for most people a hand = "do something" ... whether than means to do something dynamically on the page or load a new page. Nowadays the lines are blurred.

Answer (score 1):

Web Interfaces don't have any standardized elements as every OS does. Since the web Interfaces iCloud and Onedrive cursor varies form their desktop OS standards.

If you consider iCloud and Onedrive both are having their native and web Interfaces, In Native they use Default cursor on a button, while in the Web they use hand cursor on buttons.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A button is, in a subtle way, different from a link. Whilst a link merely replaces the current page with another, a button - usually - submits some user input and, often, affects stored data somewhere. So a distinction is reasonable.

However, since I usually leave my buttons styled obviously as buttons, and links likewise, I'll often style the button's pointer to donate 'action' with the hand.

Answer (score 0):

While other answers talk about how hand pointer should not be used, I am realizing that most web buttons do have a hand pointer:

- StackOverflow sets it on their buttons (in this very form).
- Google sets it on their buttons (check front page).
- [Tailwind](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/css/preflight.css#L322-L325) sets it in their preflight CSS reset.

So I think users are currently used for the hand pointer on buttons on the web.